# Multi Topic Consumer Identify topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I have a consumer that consumes from two topics with two different avro schemas. The number of topics can grow in the future, so unioning schemas to read from multiple topics is not scalable.

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer

# assume config for group.id and bootstrap servers are set

consumer = Consumer(config)
consumer.subscribe(["randomtopic1", "randomtopic2"])
msg = consumer.poll()
msg_value = message.value() #Should be in bytes or str
```

How do I identify/extract which topic the message is from, without deserializing it with the avro schema? Wondering if topic name is encoded into any avro headers, I came across this [link](https://towardsdev.com/consume-avro-messages-from-kafka-without-schema-716b05b9f72b) where they deserialize in the form of bytes and somehow extract the topic name. Then they deserialize the message value with the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "Avro headers" in the consumed records. *Kafka record headers* don't have the topic name (usually).

You can simply use [`message.topic()`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.Message.topic), then use an `if` statement against it to process the topics differently.

Answer (score -1):

I am not too much sure about python, but as per the confluent recommendation, if you are using a single consumer that needs to subscribe to multiple topics and handles multiple data types at the same time, it is advised to use GenericRecord instead of a specific code binding type.

You can find a sample .NET code here https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AvroGeneric/Program.cs

Comment: The question was asking for the topic, not how to deserialize the records. Python isn't typed, so "GenericRecord" isn't needed, as Avro data should be a dict type.